# Javascript getting custom async and await functions to work

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, async-await

I am building my own borwserside javascript sdk, using webpack and node.

I have a simple authenticate function which i have created in my sdk. its a simple callback function which queries an api and returns if the result was a success or not in form of a callback.

**sdk.js**

```
  async authenticate(callback) {

        try {

            this.account = await this.repo.authenticate(this.product, this.origin);

            if (this.account.success === false) {
                return callback({
                    "success": false,
                    "response": "Failed To Authenticate"
                });
            }

            return callback({
                "success": true,
                "response": this.account
            });


        } catch (e) {

            return callback({
                "success": false,
                "response": e
            });

        }

    }
```

Now in my browser i have a index file. Which will instantiate the object and call this function.

**index.html**

```
<script>

hsp = new HSP();

// function called on button click
async function done() {

    // Works
    hsp.authenticate((res) => {
        console.log(res);
     });

     // DOES NOT WORK
    try {
        const auth = await hsp.authenticate();

        console.log(auth);

    } catch (er) {
        console.log(er);
    }

}

</script>
```

In the above example in index.html the callback version of authenticate works but the await/async version of authenticate in the try catch block does not work. Why and how do i get this to work.

I want both options to work.

I get the following error. Which references the catch block and the console.log(er).

> TypeError: t is not a function
>       at t.value (index.js:41)

Comment: `t is not a function at t.value` You don't have `t` or `t.value` anywhere in the code you posted...

Comment: `authenticate` is callback-based. You can't simply `await` it to magically turn it Promise-based - it needs to return a `Promise` in order to `await` it

Comment: i think thats because its minified?

Comment: Don't try to debug minified code - instead, debug while using the *source* code so that you (and others) can figure out what the errors actually mean

Comment: Your `authenticate` function takes a `callback` as argument, but here `const auth = await hsp.authenticate();` you pass no callback.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two methodologies `callbacks` and `promises`. It's more powerful to use `promises`, and async functions make use of promises they allow you to write promise-based code as if it were synchronous, but without blocking the main thread.

> **[Async return values](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions)**
>
> Async functions always return a promise, whether
>   you use await or not. That promise resolves with whatever the async
>   function returns, or rejects with whatever the async function throws.

**Make use of your callback outside of the async function in then or catch.**

**`sdk.js`**

```
async authenticate() {

        try {

            this.account = await this.repo.authenticate(this.product, this.origin);

            if (this.account.success === false) {
                return {
                    "success": false,
                    "response": "Failed To Authenticate"
                };
            }

            return {
                "success": true,
                "response": this.account
            };


        } catch (e) {

            return {
                "success": false,
                "response": e
            };

        }

    }
```

**`index.html`**

```
<script>

hsp = new HSP();

// function called on button click
async function done() {

    // Works (Your callback here in then method)
    hsp.authenticate().then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
     }).cath( err => console.log(er));

     // It Will WORK (Make use of your callback outside of the async function)
    try {
        const auth = await hsp.authenticate();

        console.log(auth);

    } catch (er) {
        console.log(er);
    }

}

</script>
```

I hope this will help.